# How should i set my "http_read_time_out" for my new aws lambda client creation to avoid Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError: Net::ReadTimeout

Tags: aws-lambda, socket-timeout-exception

What is http_read_time_out, how should i set it in my aws lambda client creation to avoid "Seahorse::Client::NetworkingError: Net::ReadTimeout" ?

Does it make sense to set http_read_time_out as same as aws lambda function's timeout that we set while configuring a lambda function ?

I understand the default timeout is 60 secs.

```
conn = aws_lambda_client.new(
                region: region,
                access_key_id: account['access_key'],
                secret_access_key: account['secret_key'],
                session_token: account['session_token'],
              )
Can i add something like 
http_read_timeout: (function.function_timeout? && function.function_timeout > 60) ? function.function_timeout : 60
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set the lambda function timeout which is 3 sec by default
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-console.html

If you are performaing sync calls then you have to set the read_timeout of your Lambda client for async there should not be blocking calls.

> In Java (SDK v2) you could do this by following

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-lambda.html

> Specify custom HTTP client

```
SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().socketTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(2)).build();

LambdaClient client = LambdaClient.builder()
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_1)
                .httpClient(httpClient)
                .overrideConfiguration(
                        ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
                        .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3)).build())
                .build();
```